# Confusing Java syntax

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, syntax, maze

I'm trying to convert the following code (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPrim_Maze.svg)) from Java to JavaScript:

```
/*
 * 3 June 2003, [[:en:User:Cyp]]:
 *     Maze, generated by my algorithm
 * 24 October 2006, [[:en:User:quin]]:
 *     Source edited for clarity
 * 25 January 2009, [[:en:User:DebateG]]:
 *     Source edited again for clarity and reusability
 * 1 June 2009, [[:en:User:Nandhp]]:
 *     Source edited to produce SVG file when run from the command-line
 *
 * This program was originally written by [[:en:User:Cyp]], who
 * attached it to the image description page for an image generated by
 * it on en.wikipedia. The image was licensed under CC-BY-SA-3.0/GFDL.
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.Random;

/* Define the bit masks */
class Constants {
    public static final int WALL_ABOVE = 1;
    public static final int WALL_BELOW = 2;
    public static final int WALL_LEFT = 4;
    public static final int WALL_RIGHT = 8;
    public static final int QUEUED = 16;
    public static final int IN_MAZE = 32;
}

public class Maze extends java.applet.Applet {
    /* The width and height (in cells) of the maze */
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int maze[][];
    private static final Random rnd = new Random();

    /* The width in pixels of each cell */
    private int cell_width;

    /* Construct a Maze with the default width, height, and cell_width */
    public Maze() {
 this(20,20,10);
    }

    /* Construct a Maze with specified width, height, and cell_width */
    public Maze(int width, int height, int cell_width) {
 this.width = width;
 this.height = height;
 this.cell_width = cell_width;
    }

    /* Initialization method that will be called when the program is
     * run from the command-line. Maze will be written as SVG file. */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 Maze m = new Maze();
 m.createMaze();
 m.printSVG();
    }

    /* Initialization method that will be called when the program is
     * run as an applet. Maze will be displayed on-screen. */
    public void init() {
 createMaze();
    }

    /* The maze generation algorithm. */
    private void createMaze(){
 int x, y, n, d;
 int dx[] = { 0, 0, -1, 1 };
 int dy[] = { -1, 1, 0, 0 };

 int todo[] = new int[height * width], todonum = 0;

 /* We want to create a maze on a grid. */
 maze = new int[width][height];

 /* We start with a grid full of walls. */
 for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
     for (y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
  if (x == 0 || x == width - 1 || y == 0 || y == height - 1) {
      maze[x][y] = Constants.IN_MAZE;
  } else {
      maze[x][y] = 63;
  }
     }
 }

 /* Select any square of the grid, to start with. */
 x = 1 + rnd.nextInt (width - 2);
 y = 1 + rnd.nextInt (height - 2);

 /* Mark this square as connected to the maze. */
 maze[x][y] &= ~48;

 /* Remember the surrounding squares, as we will */
 for (d = 0; d < 4; ++d) {
     if ((maze[][d][][d] & Constants.QUEUED) != 0) {
  /* want to connect them to the maze. */              
  todo[todonum++] = ((x + dx[d]) << Constants.QUEUED) | (y + dy[d]);
  maze[][d][][d] &= ~Constants.QUEUED;
     }
 }

 /* We won't be finished until all is connected. */
 while (todonum > 0) {
     /* We select one of the squares next to the maze. */
     n = rnd.nextInt (todonum);
     x = todo[n] >> 16; /* the top 2 bytes of the data */
     y = todo[n] & 65535; /* the bottom 2 bytes of the data */

     /* We will connect it, so remove it from the queue. */
     todo[n] = todo[--todonum];

     /* Select a direction, which leads to the maze. */
     do {
  d = rnd.nextInt (4);
     }
     while ((maze[][d][][d] & Constants.IN_MAZE) != 0);

     /* Connect this square to the maze. */
     maze[x][y] &= ~((1 << d) | Constants.IN_MAZE);
     maze[][d][][d] &= ~(1 << (d ^ 1));

     /* Remember the surrounding squares, which aren't */
     for (d = 0; d < 4; ++d) {
  if ((maze[][d][][d] & Constants.QUEUED) != 0) {      
      /* connected to the maze, and aren't yet queued to be. */
      todo[todonum++] = ((x + dx[d]) << Constants.QUEUED) | (y + dy[d]);
      maze[][d][][d] &= ~Constants.QUEUED;
  }
     }
            /* Repeat until finished. */
        }

        /* Add an entrance and exit. */
        maze[1][1] &= ~Constants.WALL_ABOVE; 
        maze[width - 2][height - 2] &= ~Constants.WALL_BELOW;
    }

    /* Called by the applet infrastructure to display the maze on-screen. */
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
 drawMaze(g);
    }

    /* Called to write the maze to an SVG file. */
    public void printSVG() {
 System.out.format("<svg width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\" version=\"1.1\""
     + " xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">\n",
     width*cell_width, height*cell_width);
 System.out.println("  <g stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"1\""
      + " stroke-linecap=\"round\">");
 drawMaze(null);
 System.out.println("  </g>\n</svg>");
    }

    /* Main maze-drawing loop. */
    public void drawMaze(Graphics g) {
        int x, y;

        for (x = 1; x < width - 1; ++x) {
            for (y = 1; y < height - 1; ++y) {
                if ((maze[x][y] & Constants.WALL_ABOVE) != 0)
      drawLine(      x * cell_width,       y * cell_width,
        (x + 1) * cell_width,       y * cell_width, g);
                if ((maze[x][y] & Constants.WALL_BELOW) != 0)
      drawLine(      x * cell_width, (y + 1) * cell_width,
        (x + 1) * cell_width, (y + 1) * cell_width, g);
                if ((maze[x][y] & Constants.WALL_LEFT) != 0)
      drawLine(      x * cell_width,       y * cell_width,
              x * cell_width, (y + 1) * cell_width, g);
                if ((maze[x][y] & Constants.WALL_RIGHT) != 0)
      drawLine((x + 1) * cell_width,       y * cell_width,
        (x + 1) * cell_width, (y + 1) * cell_width, g);
     }
 }
    }

    /* Draw a line, either in the SVG file or on the screen. */
    public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Graphics g) {
 if ( g != null ) g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
 else System.out.format("    <line x1=\"%d\" y1=\"%d\""
          + " x2=\"%d\" y2=\"%d\" />\n", x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Anyway, I was chugging along fairly quickly when I came to a bit that I just don't understand:

```
 /* Remember the surrounding squares, as we will */
 for (var d = 0; d < 4; ++d) {
     if ((maze[][d][][d] & Constants.QUEUED) != 0) {
  /* want to connect them to the maze. */              
  todo[todonum++] = ((x + dx[d]) << Constants.QUEUED) | (y + dy[d]);
  maze[][d][][d] &= ~Constants.QUEUED;
     }
 }
```

What I don't get is why there are four sets of brackets following the "maze" parameter instead of just two, since "maze" is a two dimensional array, not a four dimensional array.

I'm sure there's a good reason for this. Problem is, I just don't *get* it.

Thanks!

Comment: Ignore [] empty brackets. This is just a typo and lead to compilation error.

Comment: DO you have a link to the article?

Comment: The link is in the post at the top.

Comment: Problem with ignoring empty brackets is that maybe they at one time weren't empty. For instance "maze[dx[d]][dy[d]]" or something.

Comment: Good catch. I would start from original pseudo code algorithm then.

Comment: OK, with some guesswork I was able to determine that "maze[][d][][d]" is supposed to be "maze[x + dx[d]][y + dy[d]]". I have it working now in JavaScript. Will post once I clean it up.

Answer (score 4):

To simply correct the syntax, this answer is as good as any.  However to fix the algorithm, [Leon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622169/confusing-java-syntax/4622315#4622315)'s has more insight there.

---

Looks to me like the code is wrong having two too many sets of square brackets.  `maze` is declared and initialized as a 2-dimensional `int` array.  There's no reason it should have more than that.  Perhaps the result of a misinformed or buggy code generator?

Just remove the preceding, empty square brackets `[]` (or `][`) from the array accesses and you'll be set.

Answer (score 3):

My educated guess would be that there is some code missing. Removing the extra [] makes the code compile but it does not generate a maze but is stuck in an infinite loop

I think [][d][][d] are supposed to be maze[x+dx[d]][y+dy[d]].

It is clear that d is supposed to index into dx and dy arrays, which are offsets into the neighbours of the current cell, as is is always iterated 4 times. Also `todo[todonum++] = ((x + dx[d]) << Constants.QUEUED) | (y + dy[d]);` indexes the maze array using dx[d] and dy[y] as offsets to the neighbours.

I am not sure whether this is the best way thou, as when x=0 and dx offset is -1 you will have and OutOfBoundsException. You may have to handle those cases explicitly.

Comment: Crap. There's no way for me to debug this without the compiler. Part of the reason why I was trying to convert it to JavaScript.

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia page history, it appears there used to be other versions that were modified over time. But they were deleted when the page was moved to Wikimedia Commons.

Comment: Are there any other dependencies I need to download before running eclipse?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure. It ran on by setup when I copied and pasted it and took out extra[], did not produce the maze, but was enough to debug. I have Galileo 3.5 but should run on most other configurations too

Comment: Ah this is likely the cause.  I'm actually more familiar with Kruskal's algorithm so I didn't recognize the problem from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the JavaScript version:

```
/*
 * 3 June 2003, [[:en:User:Cyp]]:
 *     Maze, generated by my algorithm
 * 24 October 2006, [[:en:User:quin]]:
 *     Source edited for clarity
 * 25 January 2009, [[:en:User:DebateG]]:
 *     Source edited again for clarity and reusability
 * 1 June 2009, [[:en:User:Nandhp]]:
 *     Source edited to produce SVG file when run from the command-line
 * 7 January, 2011 [[:en:User:SharkD]]:
 *     Source converted to JavaScript
 *
 * This program was originally written by [[:en:User:Cyp]], who
 * attached it to the image description page for an image generated by
 * it on en.wikipedia. The image was licensed under CC-BY-SA-3.0/GFDL.
 */

/* Recreate a math function that exists in Java but not JavaScript. */
Math.nextInt = function (number) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * number)
}

/* Recreate a system function that exists in Java but not JavaScript.
 * Uncomment either WScript.Echo() or alert() depending on whether you are
 * running the script from the Windows command-line or a Web page.
 */
function println(string)
{
 // if inside Windows Scripting Host
// WScript.Echo(string)
 // if inside a Web page
 alert(string)
}

/* Define the bit masks */
var Constants =
{
 WALL_ABOVE : 1,
 WALL_BELOW : 2,
 WALL_LEFT : 4,
 WALL_RIGHT : 8,
 QUEUED : 16,
 IN_MAZE : 32
}

/* Construct a Maze with specified width, height, and cell_width */
function Maze(width, height, cell_width) {
 if (width)
  this.width = width;
 else
  this.width = 20;
 if (height)
  this.height = height;
 else
  this.height = 20;
 if (cell_width)
  this.cell_width = cell_width;
 else
  this.cell_width = 10;
 this.maze = []

 /* The maze generation algorithm. */
 this.createMaze = function()  {
  var width = this.width
  var height = this.height
  var maze = this.maze
  var x, y, n, d;
  var dx = [ 0, 0, -1, 1 ];
  var dy = [ -1, 1, 0, 0 ];

  var todo = new Array(height * width);
  var todonum = 0;

  /* We want to create a maze on a grid. */
  /* We start with a grid full of walls. */
  for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
   maze[x] = []
   for (y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    if (x == 0 || x == width - 1 || y == 0 || y == height - 1) {
     maze[x][y] = Constants.IN_MAZE;
    }
    else {
     maze[x][y] = 63;
    }
   }
  }

  /* Select any square of the grid, to start with. */
  x = 1 + Math.nextInt(width - 2);
  y = 1 + Math.nextInt(height - 2);

  /* Mark this square as connected to the maze. */
  maze[x][y] &= ~48;

  /* Remember the surrounding squares, as we will */
  for (d = 0; d < 4; ++d) {
   if ((maze[x + dx[d]][y + dy[d]] & Constants.QUEUED) != 0) {
    /* want to connect them to the maze. */              
    todo[todonum++] = ((x + dx[d]) << Constants.QUEUED) | (y + dy[d]);
    maze[x + dx[d]][y + dy[d]] &= ~Constants.QUEUED;
   }
  }

  /* We won't be finished until all is connected. */
  while (todonum > 0) {
   /* We select one of the squares next to the maze. */
   n = Math.nextInt(todonum);
   x = todo[n] >> 16; /* the top 2 bytes of the data */
   y = todo[n] & 65535; /* the bottom 2 bytes of the data */

   /* We will connect it, so remove it from the queue. */
   todo[n] = todo[--todonum];

   /* Select a direction, which leads to the maze. */
   do {
    d = Math.nextInt(4);
   }
   while ((maze[x + dx[d]][y + dy[d]] & Constants.IN_MAZE) != 0);

   /* Connect this square to the maze. */
   maze[x][y] &= ~((1 << d) | Constants.IN_MAZE);
   maze[x + dx[d]][y + dy[d]] &= ~(1 << (d ^ 1));

   /* Remember the surrounding squares, which aren't */
   for (d = 0; d < 4; ++d) {
    if ((maze[x + dx[d]][y + dy[d]] & Constants.QUEUED) != 0) {      
     /* connected to the maze, and aren't yet queued to be. */
     todo[todonum++] = ((x + dx[d]) << Constants.QUEUED) | (y + dy[d]);
     maze[x + dx[d]][y + dy[d]] &= ~Constants.QUEUED;
    }
   }
   /* Repeat until finished. */
  }

  /* Add an entrance and exit. */
  maze[1][1] &= ~Constants.WALL_ABOVE; 
  maze[width - 2][height - 2] &= ~Constants.WALL_BELOW;
 }
 /* Called to write the maze to an SVG file. */
 this.printSVG = function () {
  var outstring = "<svg width=\"" + (width * cell_width) + "\" height=\"" + (height*cell_width) + "\" version=\"1.1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">\n"
    + "  <g stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"1\" stroke-linecap=\"round\">\n"
    + this.drawMaze()
    + "  </g>\n</svg>\n";
  println(outstring)
 }
 /* Main maze-drawing loop. */
 this.drawMaze = function () {
  var x, y;
  var width = this.width;
  var height = this.height;
  var cell_width = this.cell_width
  var outstring = ""
  for (x = 1; x < width - 1; ++x) {
   for (y = 1; y < height - 1; ++y) {
    if ((this.maze[x][y] & Constants.WALL_ABOVE) != 0)
     outstring += this.drawLine(      x * cell_width,       y * cell_width,  (x + 1) * cell_width,       y * cell_width);
    if ((this.maze[x][y] & Constants.WALL_BELOW) != 0)
     outstring += this.drawLine(      x * cell_width, (y + 1) * cell_width,  (x + 1) * cell_width, (y + 1) * cell_width);
    if ((this.maze[x][y] & Constants.WALL_LEFT) != 0)
     outstring += this.drawLine(      x * cell_width,       y * cell_width,  x * cell_width, (y + 1) * cell_width);
    if ((this.maze[x][y] & Constants.WALL_RIGHT) != 0)
     outstring += this.drawLine((x + 1) * cell_width,       y * cell_width,  (x + 1) * cell_width, (y + 1) * cell_width);
   }
  }
  return outstring
 }
 /* Draw a line, either in the SVG file or on the screen. */
 this.drawLine = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return "    <line x1=\"" + x1 + "\" y1=\"" + y1 + "\" x2=\"" + x2 + "\" y2=\"" + y2 + "\" />\n";
 }
}



/* Initialization method that will be called when the program is
* run from the command-line. Maze will be written as SVG file. */
function main(args) {
 var m = new Maze();
 m.createMaze();
 m.printSVG();
}

/* execute the program */
main()
```

Next step is to turn it into a six axis 3D maze and convert to Lua, which is my actual target platform. :)

PS - I'm trying to vote on answers, but it's telling me I need to login or register, wtf?

Comment: does it generate a maze that you want?